# How to verify 301 redirect

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Other than having to install something like Fiddler on my server, after adding a redirect in IIS, is there a log or something or a way built-in to show me that a valid 301 redirect took place other than seeing it redirect at runtime?  I guess what I want is true proof so that I can verify it's really doing the 301 for SEO even though I did state in IIS in the redirect module to 301 redirect as the kind of redirect.  I don't trust the UI until I can verify the response if you know what I mean.  The worst case I guess I could install fiddler and watch the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TELNET to your server on port 80.  Type the following:

```
GET /your.url HTTP/1.1
Host: your.hostname.here
```

Follow it with two blank lines, and you should see the response in your telnet window.  If the first line of response headers looks something like `HTTP/1.x 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY`, then its working.

**EDIT:** Of course, nobody should actually use telnet anymore, when we have tools like [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) available.

Comment: I say telnet is fine for small things like this.

Comment: Yeah, probably so.  I wasn't referring to the plaintext insecurity issue, though, so much as the fact that PuTTY supports a RAW mode - using that you don't have to worry about your client ever attempting funky stuff like telnet parameter negotiation.  And PuTTY has better support for unix-style linefeeds than telnet, so the results are more readable.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler isn't installed on your server. you install it on the the client. I'd use fiddler, or the net tab of [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: I'm saying that if I'm doing something through remote, and changing stuff in IIS on the server, much quicker to just fire it up there...that's all.  And I more wanted to know if there were tools on the server itself such as telnet as the guy below is saying that I can just use when I'm remoted in.